# Jruby :- Unable to install devise on windows using jruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, jruby, devise

unable to install devise on windows using jruby

### ===============================================

C:>jruby -S gem install devise
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing devise:
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/jruby-1.5.3/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Gem files will remain installed in c:/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/
gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-
ruby-2.1.2/ext/mri/gem_make.out

### ===============================================

can we build native extension using jruby, just like in ruby using
DevKit, somethig like in jruby in windows

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this out, and I am so glad I did because I am using Devise for a production application that is being deployed to Tomcat, and bcrypt was causing me grief. ANYWAY, here's what you do:

1. Make sure you are using a version of Ruby from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

   - Download and install which ever version of Ruby you want
   - I should mention that I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and have not tested this for Ruby 1.9+
2. Download the latest DevKit as well from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

   - Extract DevKit, but do not set it up at this point
3. Download and install JRuby
4. At this point, both RubyInstaller Ruby and JRuby should be available on your path

   - A simple check would be is to open a command prompt window and type

     - `jruby -v` outputs `jruby 1.5.5 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 249) (2010-11-10 4bd4200) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_21) [x86-java]`
     - `ruby -v` outputs `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]`
5. `cd` to the directory where you extracted DevKit
6. Type `ruby dk.rb init`
7. **IMPORTANT:** Open `config.yml` and make sure that both your jruby and ruby installations are listed. If not, **ADD** them. Save and close `config.yml` after you're done.
8. Back in your command prompt window, type `ruby dk.rb install`. This will install DevKit to all the ruby installations listed in your `config.yml`. Most important of all, **IT WILL ALSO INSTALL IT INTO YOUR JRUBY INSTALLATION!**
9. Once installation is done, give it a whirl by typing `jruby -S gem install bcrypt-jruby`

   ```
   C:\>jruby -S gem install bcrypt-ruby --no-ri --no-rdoc
   JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
   gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
   Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
   Successfully installed bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2
   1 gem installed
   ```

BINGO! BANGO!

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt-ruby now comes with pre-built java gems as of 3.0.1, so you won't need to compile your own to get up and running with Rail 3.1